# The Maxwell and the Boltzmann distributions

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I am trying to understand where the Boltzmann distribution comes from. I recently learned some interesting things of which my interpretation follows below. Did I interpret correctly? If so, is this all there is to it, or is this only part of the story?

When sampling coordinates in a high-dimensional Euclidean space as independent and identically distributed Gaussians, you are essentially uniformly sampling on a sphere in that space. Maxwell and Boltzmann were well aware of this.

The equiprobability principle loosely asserts that configurations at the same energy occur with equal probability.

In an $N$ particle system in 3-space at constant total kinetic energy $E_\text{kin}$, it can be derived that the equiprobability principle is consistent in the thermodynamic limit $N\to\infty$ with each velocity component of each constituent particle being independently distributed with probability distribution

$$\pi(v_i^\alpha) \propto e^{-\frac12{m(v_i^\alpha)^2\over k_BT}}= e^{-{E_\text{kin, i}^\alpha\over k_BT}}$$

where $i$ indexes the constituent particles and $\alpha$ the coordinates; namely, this leads to a distribution of $r = \sqrt{\sum\|v_i\|^2}$ of the form

$$\pi(r) \propto r^{3N-1}e^{-\frac12 m{r^2\over k_BT}} = r^{3N-1}e^{-{E_\text{kin}\over k_BT}}$$

($3N$ is the total number of velocity degrees of freedom). For large $N$, this distribution peaks sharply around $r = \sqrt{(3N - 1){k_BT\over m}} \approx \sqrt{3N{k_BT\over m}}$ and since the average kinetic energy per particle is $E_\text{kin,i} = {3\over2}k_BT$, this is equal to $r\approx\sqrt{{2\over m}E_\text{kin}}$, at which value indeed the kinetic energy is $E_\text{kin}$.

Boltzmann postulated that this still holds when the total energy is non-constant, and not only for components of individual particles, but for entire subsystems, so that the probability of any configuration of energy $E$ becomes proportional to

$$\pi(E) \propto e^{-{E\over k_BT}}$$

Comment: Doesn't your second displayed equation have to be wrong since the energy is fixed?

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs For finite $N$ this gives a distribution of values for $r$, hence for the kinetic energy, but for large $N$ this tends to a distribution that is supported on $\sqrt{{2\over m}E}$; in other words, we tend to a constant energy in the limit for large $N$. It would have been more precise to call $E_\text{kin}$ the modal kinetic energy. Or is this not what you were referring to?

Comment: You say, "In an $N$ particle system in 3-space at constant total kinetic energy $E_{kin}$, it can be derived that...", and you go on to derive a distribution for $r$. I am saying that the distribution for $r$ should be consistent with $p(E) = \delta(E-E_{kin})$.

Comment: I formulated sloppily. I should have said that an $N$-particle system with this distribution of velocity components has a modal total kinetic energy equal to $E_\text{kin}$. As $N$ increases, the whole distribution tends to a Dirac mass. (An $N$-particle system with independent velocity distributions cannot have constant kinetic energy, except in the thermodynamic limit)